# how to use chrome.history in android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-browser

I am trying to develop an app that access browser history but I know that since Android 6 the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions are removed ([docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)). 
Does someone know if it is possible to access chrome history or bookmark, on Android, using the chrome.history API ([docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history))?